# Setting dynamic value of <jsp:param> using javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp

i have a input hidden field which has a value

```
<input type="text" name="ip_hide" id="ip_hide" value="suppose a ip">
```

this value i can set it by javascript function using document.getElementById().value method..

below this input field i have to load a jsp page dynamically. so i use

```
<jsp:include="dynamic.jsp">
<jsp:param name="ip" value="?"/>
</jsp:include>
```

I want to fetch the value from hidden input field and try to set it in `jsp:param` value ..

Is it possible by javascript ?? Or if there is another way then plz grab my attention

Answer (score 0):

On the same page? You're confused as to the fact that JSP runs on the server and serves the page to the browser, and then the Javascript runs in the browser.  So by the time you've changed the value in javascript, the JSP is no longer running.

If, on the other hand, you mean after the user clicks a submit button on a form and the post or get request is sent to the server again, then you just use request.getParameter:

```
<jsp:include="dynamic.jsp">
<jsp:param name="ip" value="<%= request.getParameter("ip_hide") %>"/>
</jsp:include>
```

By the way, if you want the value to be hidden on your HTML form (its not really hidden if the user views source, hidden just means not visible on the rendered page) then you should do type='hidden' not type='text':

```
<input type="hidden" name="ip_hide" id="ip_hide" value="suppose a ip" />
```